# Changing ArcSDE connection credentials for map document?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3

Is it possible to change the ArcSDE credentials used by an MXD, so that users with the same connection can open the MXD and use their own username and password to access that data?

With our current setup, if we share an MXD, the person attempting to open it will be prompted for username and password, however since it's not the same as the person who created it, the connection is unable to be made and the account of the opening person becomes locked (if attempted 3 times).

Using ArcMap 10.3, ArcSDE is on Oracle database

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of ArcGIS and the database product.  It's certainly possible to uncheck the save credentials option, so that both user *and* password are prompted.

Comment: yes, un-checking the button will result in the user and password being prompted, however because the database connection is configured using the creating user's credentials, someone else opening the MXD and entering their credentials will receive an 'incorrect username/password' error. BUT, there's a solution...

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of a play around, and obtaining a test MXD containing a colleague's database connection, here's the solution:

- In ArcCatalog, right-click the MXD and select 'Set Data Source(s)'.
- Select the layers which have a current data source of another user's database connection. If all layers, click Select All.
- Depending on if you selected some, or all, click either Replace or Replace All.
- In the Replace/Replace All window, enter the path to your database connection (.sde) file.

  [image]
- Click Replace/Replace All and click OK. A copy of the MXD will be create with the new connection details.